# What does $E^{\mathbb{C}}$ mean?

Tags: vector-spaces, notation

I was reading a book (Symplectic Geometry and Quantum Mechanics) and find it hard to understand this following example:

*Definition:* a "complex structure" on a vector space $E$ is any linear isomorphism $j:E \rightarrow E $
such that $j^2 = - I$.

*Example:* Let $j$ be a complex structure on a vector space $E$. Show that one can define on $E$ a structure of complex vector space $E^{\mathbb{C}}$ by setting
$$(\alpha + i \beta)z = a + \beta j z.$$

I don't quite understand what is the meaning of the symbol $E^{\mathbb{C}}$ by putting $\mathbb{C}$ on the right top position. What is the meaning of a symbol when a set is put on the right top position?

Comment: I suppose it means $\mathbf C$ acts on the group $E$.

Comment: This is also sometimes used to denote the collection of maps $\mathbb{C}\to E$.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you so much. I haven't learned this concept, so I didn't get it before.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you so much.

Comment: I think it's just notation to denote that $E$ has been complexified; nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Okay, now I think it just means "$E$, but regarded as a complex vector space."

Comment: But then where does the complex structure on $E$ come in?

Comment: @Zhen: oh, hmm. Yeah, never mind. I thought the example was doing something more sophisticated than it was.

Comment: In my defense, this notation now conflicts with at least *three* other uses of the exponential notation $(-)^{(-)}$.